# Enter Multiple rows in Data.Frame cell R

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any solution to add in single cell in data.frame expression with multiple rows ? e.i

Single cell should look like:

|This is single row         |
|expresion in R data frame  |
|Simple Example             |

Comment: You can use a "\n" separated string.

Comment: Is this specifically for shiny? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the purpose? You can include a break character as Bing Sun suggests, you can include `<br/>` if you want a line break to be displayed in html. You can even nest a list within a cell.

Comment: I create app which allow users to add new and update current comments. I want add values to reactive data frame and display same current komment as rendertext in separate tab.

Comment: Used <br> and htmlOutput works fine for me thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked! If that solved your problem could you mark my answer?